# How can I merge multiple custom filter that do the same filtering but dealing with different entity?

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I have this Customer Filters I made such as:

```
public static class Filters
{
  public static IQueryable<Item> IsActive(this IQueryable<Item> qry)
  {
    return from i in qry
           where i.Status == 1
           select i;
  }

  public static IQueryable<Customer> IsActive(this IQueryable<Customer> qry)
  {
    return from c in qry
           where c.Status == 1
           select c;
  }
}
```

As you can see, both do the same. Returns all the `entity` where `status` is equals to `1`. Is there a way to merge them? So that in the future, I decided to add another `entity` say `Foo` will also get the filtering. Will I also take into account the `entities` and check if the entity have the property `Status`?

Is this possible? A sample code would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option so you don't need to include a whole new library is to introduce a common interface for the two classes:

```
public interface IHasStatus
{
    int Status { get; }
}
```

Then you just need to have your classes implement the interface and you can change your function to:

```
public static IQueryable<T> IsActive<T>(this IQueryable<T> qry) where T : IHasStatus
{
    return from i in qry where i.Status == 1 select i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [linq.dynamic](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/) to pass the column as string

```
public static class Filters
{
    public static IQueryable<T> IsActive<T>(this IQueryable<T> qry)
    {
        return qry.Where("Status = @0", 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this be applicable to all entity?

Comment: Yes, it can. I updated my answer, I forgot to provide generic method.

Comment: I'm havingan eror. `The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found`. Any thoughts?

Comment: hmmm, that's weird, it works fine at my place, is it compile time error / run time error? could you just copy paste the whole code above and try it again?